# How to remove 'insert' paths in gazebo UI

Tags: gazebo

I added some paths for model insertion in the gazebo UI. I have since move the projects elsewhere or deleted some of the models but can't seem to figure out how to delete the paths showing up under the insert tab. Is it possible to delete paths once you add them?

Here's an image that points shows the image that I have but doesn't include my paths, which is how I would like mine to look. 
[image: Here's an image that points shows the image that I have but doesn't include my paths]

Comment: "added some paths" -- can you provide information on how you had added those paths? Did you edit your bashrc for eg? Or some other way?

Comment: I used the gazebo GUI, the "Insert" tab. Not bashrc.

Comment: The "Insert" tab is for importing models that Gazebo can already find in its related environment variables.  What I meant is when you say "added some paths for model insertion", how/where did you add those paths? 
http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=components&cat=get_started#EnvironmentVariables

Comment: MorganStark47, I added them by clicking on the "Add Path" button right below the insert tab.